# Qual o jeito mais eficiente de pegar uma informação em um site qualquer e utilizá-la em um APP Android?

Tags: java, android, aplicação-web

Por exemplo: Um aplicativo que acesse o site https://dolarhoje.com/ e pegue o valor do dólar atual e mostre no aplicativo. Quais as formas de se fazer isso?

Comment: Você teria que criar/usar alguma biblioteca que lê html para fazer um "scrap" no html, ou procurar alguma API que forneça as informações que você quer

Comment: Poderia me dizer alguma biblioteca que faz isso?

Comment: Pra android/java não sei te informar, sou PHP :/

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito mais eficiente é utilizando um [webservice](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

Mas como não vivemos em um mundo perfeito, nem sempre usar um webservice é  uma opção. Nestes casos você pode usar uma biblioteca como o [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) para percorrer o HTML e buscar a informação que você precisa.

Para consultar o site que você quer com o jsoup, é possível fazer:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dolarhoje.com/").get();
Element newsHeadlines = doc.select("#nacional").first();
String dolarHoje = newsHeadlines.attr("value");
```

Comment: Era mais ou menos isso que eu tinha em mente, percorrer um HTML. Mas vou dar um exemplo que é o meu projeto pessoal... Eu pretendo acessar a URL https://sofifa.com/players?keyword= em que o usuário entraria no app com uma keyword e o site retornaria com os resultados. Entretanto ele pode retornar vários resultados, deixando o retorno do Jsoup um pouco grande... isso não poderia ser um problema ou deixar o app mais lento?

Comment: Lento é relativo. O ideal é você testar e ver se o tempo é aceitável para o seu caso de uso. Na minha conexão o site que você mencionou demorou entre 1,5 e 1,6 segundos para ser parseado pelo jsoup. Uma alternativa para o seu problema é criar seu próprio webservice como uma "camada de cache" e consumi-lo no app. O seu webservice consultaria o site de tempos em tempos e manteria em memoria ou banco as informações coletadas para o seu app.

Comment: Vou estudar por este lado então. Ótima resposta, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se uma resposta do site o ajudou, não esqueça de marcá-la como aceita para que outros usuários a achem com mais facilidade. =)

Answer (score 1):

Em geral você não vai pegar uma informação lendo um site, o mais comum é usar uma API que retorne isso em um formato JSON ou XML. O formato mais usado é o JSON por ser mais leve e rápido, nesse caso você pode usar a biblioteca [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) para fazer o parse e retornar um objeto do java

Dependendo do que pretende pode usar uma [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView), explicando de forma simplificada, permite aos aplicativos que abram janelas do navegador de forma interna, sem ter que ‘chamar’ o navegador externamente, e assim abrindo uma outra aplicação, consumindo mais recursos do smartphone.

Como comentado, também é possível usar uma biblioteca que lê o HTML e depois você pode filtrar o retorno e mostrar os dados que quer, não conheço nenhuma mas sei que existe